# (??=) Double question mark and an equal sign, what does that operator do?

Tags: operator-keyword, php-7.4

Once I stumbled with php7 code with operator `??=`. I tried to search, what it clearly does, but could not find easily. I tried to read out the php operators and even most official resources have all operators description and even compound operators like `.=`, `+=`, but there are no description for `??=`

For example, [PHP Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) keeps descriptions of all operators, as straight form (`.`, `+`), as compound (`.=`, `+=`), but there is no `??=`, and because of that I firstly was confused and thought it's something totally another.
The issue is simple and obvious, but the whole case is a bit confusing, that's why I try to help other php-beginners like me

Comment: thanks, you are right, but, you see, you just can't search it in casual way, 'cause, for example, google for your request '??=' returns nothing usefull - as for "double qestion mark equal sign" too, so you just can't find out, where information is

Comment: Check out https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So eventually I decided to write code and watch by myself - how it works and what it does.

In PHP7.0 was added the [Null Coalescing operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm):

```
$username = $_GET['username'] ?? 'not passed';
```

Our $username will have $_GET['username'] value - if it exists and not null, otherwise $username will get 'not passed' string.
But sometimes you can have a situation, when you need to check for existence and not-nullability the variable itself:

```
$first_test = $first_test ?? 'not started';
```

And in this situation you can use a compound version of null coalescing operator - **'??='**:

```
$first_test ??= 'not started';
```

That's it, just compound version of '??' for the cases, where you check the itself variable.

Comment: `??=` was only added in php 7.4 and up - [demo](https://3v4l.org/GTN0r) - [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.null-coalescing-assignment-operator)

Comment: thanks, did not know, that operator and its shorthand were released in different versions